# Error with variable interpretation with Sqoop

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, sqoop

I'm having issues passing arguments to [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html) inside a bash script.

Sqoop is a tool to transfer tables from RDB (Oracle in this particular case) to Hive. It is a command line tool invoked like this:

```
sqoop import --connect <string> --direct --table <table> --query <query> ....
```

I am generating the command to launch inside the script, taking values form a file and parsing them with awk.
All the arguments are ok, except the **--query** one. This argument is used to pass the query to use on the source for data extraction. It accept this format:

```
select very long list of columns from schema.table where \$CONDITIONS
```

THE **\$CONDITIONS** is a variable that Sqoop substitutes, so it is mandatory in this very literal format, backslash included.

I am sure that the problem is with the **--query** parameter, because if I run the script as it is, but hardcoding the value for --query in plain text, it works.

To be clear, this is the command I've got inside my script:

```
 scoop import --connect "$source" --table "$sourcetab" \
 -- hiveimport --some more other commands --querytot "$query"
```

So, for a reason I don't understand, there is a problem with this value.
So far I tried these values form **--query**:

Given:

```
query="select col1 col2 col3 col4 col4 from schema.table"
```

I already tried:

```
1. querytot="$query where \\$CONDITIONS"

2. cond=" where '\$CONDITIONS'"
   querytot="$query$cond"

3. $(echo "$query$cond")   <-- placed directly in the sqoop command

4. echo "$query$cond" > query_file, and passed it to Sqoop via --options-file
```

All of these without success.
Would you please help me ? I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Provide both the log of `bash -x yourscript` showing how it invokes the `sqoop` line, and of running a working line yourself by hand after running `set -x` (**with** the `set -x` output from that successful command-line invocation included, thus showing how the shell interpreted it).

Comment: (When you say "hardcoding the value for `--query` in plain text", it's not at all clear what quoting you're using for that, if any at all, and that's **entirely essential** information).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll provide the info you asked asap. Hardcoding means that I actually write the select statement in plain text, not using variables. That is, `--query select col1 col2 col3 from schema.table where \$CONDITIONS`

Comment: With no quotes, so `--query` is split into multiple arguments, not passed as a single one? It's an... *interesting* choice on the part of sqoop's developers for that to be their intended/correct syntax.

Comment: Anyhow, if there's no quoting at all, but a working command-line invocation just passes `--query select col1 col2 col3 from schema.table where \$CONDITIONS`, then what that means is that the backslash isn't actually literal -- it's actually syntax, itself, with the purpose of making the `$` that follows it literal. That said, I'm looking forward to seeing those logs, just because that's *so very unlikely* a decision for someone familiar with UNIX conventions to intentionally make.

Comment: Reading the docs, though, I don't actually see them doing that. The man page includes examples with argument lists like `--query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS'`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, please consider the line I posted in the comment double-quoted. It's late here and I'm tired. [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4oko59uvqfz1e82/test_log.txt?dl=0) you can find the bash -x log. Look ad line 24, a working sqoop command won't show the backslash after the where clase

Comment: Right. So the issue there is that you're using the backslash even with single-quotes, but it's needed only with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to add a literal suffix to a string is to append that suffix in single-quotes.

Reading [the documentation to sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html) makes it very clear that a query should be passed as a single argument, that the literal suffix should be `WHERE $CONDITIONS`, and that in the code given in the question, the backslash only served to make that `$` literal. In single-quotes, however, the `$` is already literal -- making the backslash unnecessary.

Thus:

```
query="select col1 col2 col3 col4 col4 from schema.table"
query+=' WHERE $CONDITIONS'

sqoop import --query "$query"
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! You saved my day. I haven't used the query+= synthax before, it worked just fine !

Comment: If you had an older shell that didn't support `+=`, by the way, you could have used `query="$query"' WHERE $CONDITIONS'` -- switching quoting types partway through the string, using double for the part where you want the expansions and single-quotes for the part where you don't. `query="$query WHERE \$CONDITIONS"` would be fine too.